# Bearer token for calling Azure Data Factory via REST API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

I'm trying to call from my Azure function REST API which will execute pipeline in Data factory. Currently I found out how to call pipeline and I managed with temp token but I'm not sure how and where to register the Azure function so I can get perm token with which I will be able to call pipeline without changing token every 15minutes.

I need suggestion where even to find bearer token (currently I found it on MS site while testing post requests).

Should I go with "App registration" and there I will got token or? Does someone know best way to implement this since I don't want to have crappy code and I can't find anything about that except "app registration".